# How to scrape Instagram Posts using snscrape

Tags: python, web-scraping, instagram

Does anyone know how to scrape Instagram using snscrape?

I've tried this, but I get "page does not exist".

```
import snscrape.modules.instagram as sninstagram
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def getUserPosts(name):
    insta_list1 = []
    
    name = 'from:' + name
    print(name)

    for i,post in enumerate(sninstagram.InstagramUserScraper(name).get_items()): #declare a username 
        
        print(post)
        
        insta_list1.append([post]) #declare the attributes to be returned
    
    return insta_list1
```

and calling it like this:

```
getUserPosts('aoc')
```

Comment: Maybe you need to use this code with a page that exists?

Comment: That page exists tho: instagram.com/aoc

Comment: But does the page `from:aoc` exist?

Answer (score 0):

There are three functions to scrape Instagram. If you want to use the InstagramUserScraper(name) function. You have to use it like this:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(snsInt.InstagramUserScraper('usernameHere').get_items())
```

It will fetch all the posts from the specified user.

There is no from: option. It`s for Twitter search queries. In InstagramUserScraper() you have to pass the username as a string. Thanks

Comment: Is there any way to scrape posts with a certain hashtag, like with Twitter? To get comments

Comment: Yes, it`s possible, however, I`m not sure this option is available in Sns.

Comment: Kindly check the Instagra API. There you will surely find this feature.